# Firebase Firestore Architecture : Reference or Object?

Tags: java, android, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing an issue that's keeping me up all night... What is the best way between those 2 solutions? FYI, I'm building a sample chat app.

**Solution 1:**

```
public class Message {
    private String message;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private DocumentReference userSender; //Reference
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
public class Message {
    private String message;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private User userSender; //Plain Object
}
```

**The first one** is very SQL like, and allows me to keep reference to user that sent a message. However, it's ***really a pain to access*** each User properties through a huge list of Message (for example within a RecyclerView).

**The second one** is more JSON like, but so ***immutable*** : for example, if an user change it's profile picture, every Message previously sent will keep the old picture...

Any solution or idea?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in Firebase Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore introduced the `Reference` as a [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), so you can take advantage of that.

Please note, that there is no best solution for that. You are free to use whatever you want, but thinking at one thing, what is the simplest way in your app to read/write data.

Using a class within another class, it's now a common practice when it comes to Firestore. In the earlier version of the database, in Firebase Realtime Database, if you had a class nested within another class (as in your example), every time you would have wanted to query your database to display only the messages, the enitire `Message` object would have downloaded togheter with the `User` object, ending to spend more bandwith. But when it comes to Collections and Documents that's not the case anymore.

Regarding the second way, you can use public setters to change the value of the fields within the object.

Working with Firestore, I can say that the second solution definitely fits me, because you can write more clear code but this is only my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

For ease of using references, a solution to that is to structure references inside one `Map<String, DocumentReference>`

```
public class Message {
    private String message;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private Map<String, DocumentReference> references;
}
```

You can create a generic class or method that would handle resolving the references whenever you retrieve the `Message`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DocumentReference` instead of `Object`, then use:

```
DocumentSnapshot pro = Tasks.await(data.getUserSender().get());
User plainObject =  pro.toObject(User.class);
```